How to split a cell and count all the unique values?
How to split a cell and count all the unique values?
Hello there! I have a table from the questionnaire. Several questions contain multiple response and the answers are collected as one person-one answer (in one cell).



id
What fruits do you like?




122
apple, grapes, kiwi


412
kiwi, mango, lemon


...
...



So I tried to split all the cells to make a table and got (example):
data['What fruits do you like'].str.split(',',expand=True)



index
1
2
3




0
apple
grapes
kiwi


1
kiwi
mango
lemon


...
...
...
...



And now I'd like to make a table, where indexes are name of fruit and values are quantity of met fruit in splitted table:



fruit
quantity




apple
1


kiwi
2


grapes
1


...
...



I tried to split a table and make a pivot_table, but I don't understand how to make a pivot only have values and indexes from 0 to 10 in columns.
I tried to write for cycle, but don't know how to collect the data.

split, explode, then value_counts:
out = (df['What fruits do you like?'].str.split(', *')
       .rename('fruit')
       .explode().value_counts()
       .reset_index(name='quantity')
      )

Output:
    fruit  quantity
0    kiwi         2
1   apple         1
2  grapes         1
3   mango         1
4   lemon         1

